# How is this not causing a cross thread exception in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, silverlight

I am aware that you need to use a Dispatcher to update items in the UI thread from a worker thread. To confirm my understanding, when you get the Dispatcher associated with current object is it always the UI dispatcher if my class inherits from the UserControl class? In which cases is it not the UI dispatcher?

Anyway, in the following code, I am creating a query and starting it asynchronously and when it completes, it sets the itemsource on one of my UI elements. I also am adding items to an observable collection that a UI element uses as its itemsource. When this is ran, it works fine and isn't fussing at me to use a dispatcher and update the UI that way. Why is that?

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask(URL);
    queryTask.ExecuteCompleted += new EventHandler<QueryEventArgs>(queryTask_ExecuteCompleted);
    queryTask.Failed += new EventHandler<TaskFailedEventArgs>(queryTask_Failed);
    Query query = new Query();
    query.Where = "Field <> 'XXX'";
    query.OutFields.Add("*");
    queryTask.ExecuteAsync(query);
    BuildingsOrganizationList.ItemsSource = organizationList;
}


void queryTask_ExecuteCompleted(object sender, QueryEventArgs e)
{
    FeatureSet featureSet = e.FeatureSet;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> columns in featureSet.FieldAliases)
    {
        TypeGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = columns.Key,
            Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Attributes[" + columns.Key + "]"),
            CanUserSort = true
        });
    }
    TypeGrid.ItemsSource = featureSet.Features;
    TypeBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;

    testing();
}

private void testing()
{
    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
    temp.Add("Item 1");
    temp.Add("Item 2");
    temp.Add("Item 3");

    foreach (string org in temp)
    {
        organizationList.Add(org);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher has to be used if you want to update your UI from another thread. ExecuteCompleted is a callback, you're not touching your UI from outside the thread it's running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because even though the processing is done asynchronously, you retrieve the result in your UI thread (an event is NOT thread), and update it from there.

If, however, you put the code inside `queryTask_ExecuteCompleted` in a Task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    //code of queryTask_ExecuteCompleted here
});
```

You will get your exception.

Comment: Then why do many articles I see on the web say to use the Dispatcher when doing async calls in silverlight. Like here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Tip-Asynchronous-Silverlight-Execute-on-the-UI-thread.aspx

Comment: You'd have to use a dispatcher if you were updating your UI in your ExecuteAsync method. You don't do it, so you don't need it. Your event handlers are on your UI thread already.

Comment: Could you give me an example of some code that would need to use the dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, it does. Quite simple isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecuteCompleted` event happens on the same thread that calls `ExecuteAsync`.